# Grant permissions to all external users on Client Side Assets library in App Catalog site

Tags: spfx-webparts, external-users, sharepoint-permissions

I have a SPFx web part added to my page in a modern SharePoint site.

External Sharing is enabled in my modern site and I need to grant at least "Read" permissions to every external user on "Client Side Assets" library in SharePoint App catalog site to get my SPFx web part to work for them, otherwise SPFx web part throws error.

However, every time when a new external user is added to the site, I need to go to App Catalog site and grant them the permissions.

**Is there an easy way to grant permissions on "ClientSideAssets" library in App Catalog site to all external users?**

There is a group named "Everyone except External user" but is there a group like "Everyone including External users"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the "All Users" or "Everyone" groups in your SPO tenant you must first enable them. Details on how to enable them from powershell are here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/Set-SPOTenant?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sharepoint-ps

You probably want to execute:
Set-SPOTenant -ShowEveryoneClaim $true

Comment: Thanks for your response, it worked at tenant level. Is there a way to enable this to particular site collection(s)? In my case, I would like to enable this only for my app catalog site. Is that possible?

Comment: There is no way to limit it to a single site as this controls whether or not the group shows up in the people picker. What you could do is enable it, go in and grant the everyone group access where it is needed in the app catalog, then disable it again. Disabling it will not remove the permissions you have assigned using the everyone group, it just hides the option from the people picker so your users won't have access to it.

Comment: Thanks, that helped.