# react-script-editor is not working for external users

Tags: sharepoint-online, apps-development, script-editor-webpart, app-catalog

I added the modern script editor web part to a modern page @ https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor .. now the web part is working well for internal users while it is raising this error for external user:-

```
Something went wrong
If the problem persists, contact the site administrator and give them the information in Technical Details.
Technical Details

[SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
Failed to load component "3a328f0a-99c4-4b28-95ab-fe0847f657a3" (ScriptEditorWebPart). Original error: Failed to load path dependency "PropertyControlStrings" from component "3a328f0a-99c4-4b28-95ab-fe0847f657a3" (ScriptEditorWebPart). Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/3a328f0a-99c4-4b28-95ab-fe0847f657a3_1.0.0/PropertyControlStrings
 Unable to load script https://***co.sharepoint.com/sites/AppCatalog/ClientSideAssets/1425175f-3ed8-44d2-8fc4-dd1497191294/react-script-editor-propertycontrolstrings_en-us_92b9e969e3f7ed4b17e1c27dfc789861.js

INNERERROR:
Failed to load path dependency "PropertyControlStrings" from component "3a328f0a-99c4-4b28-95ab-fe0847f657a3" (ScriptEditorWebPart). Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/3a328f0a-99c4-4b28-95ab-fe0847f657a3_1.0.0/PropertyControlStrings
 Unable to load script https://***co.sharepoint.com/sites/AppCatalog/ClientSideAssets/1425175f-3ed8-44d2-8fc4-dd1497191294/react-script-editor-propertycontrolstrings_en-us_92b9e969e3f7ed4b17e1c27dfc789861.js
CALLSTACK:
Error
   at t._generateErrorStackForIE (https://modern.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-gb_f0e2149359bcca08ea915a43bbe89991.js:1:870382)
   at t (https://modern.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-gb_f0e2149359bcca08ea915a43bbe89991.js:1:869900)
   at t (https://modern.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-gb_f0e2149359bcca08ea915a43bbe89991.js:1:1013797)
   at e.buildErrorWithVerboseLog (https://modern.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-gb_f0e2149359bcca08ea915a43bbe89991.js:1:1036973)
   at e.buildLoadComponentError (https://modern.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-gb_f0e2149359bcca08ea915a43bbe89991.js:1:1033012)
   at Anonymous function (https://modern.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/chunk.systemjs-component-loader_en-us_06fb90fbb103ba8a0bb1.js:1:66104)
   at Anonymous function (https://modern.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-gb_f0e2149359bcca08ea915a43bbe89991.js:1:13839)
   at C (https://modern.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-gb_f0e2149359bcca08ea915a43bbe89991.js:1:13815)
   at R (https://modern.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-gb_f0e2149359bcca08ea915a43bbe89991.js:1:13701)
   at T (https://modern.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-gb_f0e2149359bcca08ea915a43bbe89991.js:1:13279)
```

is there a way to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it seems that external users doesn't have permission to the Client Side Assets library in SharePoint App catalog site: https://***co.sharepoint.com/sites/AppCatalog/ClientSideAssets

When we deploy spfx solutions to app catalog, Client Side Assets library would host your spfx assets(js files). So we have to have permissions to the Client Side Assets library to use the web part.

Here is a similar issue for your reference: [Grant permissions to all external users on Client Side Assets library in App Catalog site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/273338/grant-permissions-to-all-external-users-on-client-side-assets-library-in-app-cat)

Comment: i access the permission settings for the https://***co.sharepoint.com/sites/AppCatalog/ClientSideAssets lib and it has unique permissions with no users inside it,, so how the internal users are using those assets then?

Comment: Have you try use  internal users  to acess the folder:  https://***co.sharepoint.com/sites/AppCatalog/ClientSideAssets/1425175f-3ed8-44d2-8fc4-dd1497191294/

Answer (score 0):

This could be a permissions problem. Ensure that external users have the appropriate read permissions to assets required by the web part to function.